# Laravel - can't redirect user to specific path after registration

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to redirect my user after registration to a page where they edit their profile, which is a path defined in routes as (and works perfectly, if I go manually to it after registration is complete):
`Route::get('/profile/{user}/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');`

However, I can't seem to get it to work when I try to redirect user to this page after registration with:

```
  protected function redirectTo(User $user) {
        return redirect('/profile/' . $user->id . '/edit');
    }
```

or

```
protected $redirectTo = "/profile/" . $user->id . "/edit/"; //invalid expression operator

protected $redirectTo = "/profile/{user}/edit";
```

This is my database Schema when creating user:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Make sure that you have `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` trait in your `LoginController`. The logic of redirecting user is implemented in `sendLoginResponse()` method. You can override this method in your `LoginController` if it is needed.

Comment: I think the problem is I'm fetching my id wrong somehow.

Comment: Where you define the `protected $redirectTo` there is no `$user` available.

Comment: But then why wouldn't something like this work then:
    
`protected function redirectTo() { return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id . '/edit/'); }`

Comment: @user14584183 is that code in the auth middleware?

Comment: No, it's code in Auth/RegisterController.php ->I get following error with this code - `protected function redirectTo(User $user) { return redirect("/profile/{$user->id}/edit"); }`

Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::redirectTo(), 0 passed in C:\Users\kleme\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\underground1\vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\RedirectsUsers.php on line 15 and exactly 1 expected

Comment: There is no User passed to the redirectTo function.  Just remove `User $user` in `protected function redirectTo(User $user) {` These kind of errors need to be in your question.

Comment: Please share the code of controller

Answer (score 0):

There is no `$user` passed to the redirect function. You need to use the auth helper and remove the function parameter. it also needs to return a path, not a redirect response:

```
 protected function redirectTo() {
        return '/profile/' . auth()->user()->id . '/edit';
    }
```

Comment: Tried it as already stated in the comments, I get the following error in Response.php: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

https://imgur.com/L5awsDJ

Comment: I edited the answer. I missed the fact that a path needs to be returned, not a redirect response. My bad.